# How to simplify the way I wrote the NgFor script?

Tags: angular, ngfor

I am trying to put the array list to one dialog.

In the dialog, When I pull the array out through NgFor, the way I wrote looks so stupid

is there any way to optimize the script?

Putting the data in Mother Page

```
  const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(NationalityDailogComponent, dialogConfig).afterClosed()
  .subscribe( data => {
    this.selectNationality = data;
            console.log(this.selectNationality);
  });
```

Getting the data in Dialog Page

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.NationlityList = this.passedData; 
}
```

Extract the data

```
<div *ngFor="let item of NationlityList.NationlityList; let i = index">
  <div *ngIf="i % 6 == 0" class="row">
      <mat-checkbox *ngIf="i + 0 < NationlityList.NationlityList.length" (change)="onCheckboxChecked($event, NationlityList.NationlityList[i].Nationality)"> {{ NationlityList.NationlityList[i].Nationality }} </mat-checkbox>
      <mat-checkbox *ngIf="i + 1 < NationlityList.NationlityList.length" (change)="onCheckboxChecked($event, NationlityList.NationlityList[i+1].Nationality)"> {{ NationlityList.NationlityList[i+1].Nationality }} </mat-checkbox>
      <mat-checkbox *ngIf="i + 2 < NationlityList.NationlityList.length" (change)="onCheckboxChecked($event, NationlityList.NationlityList[i+2].Nationality)"> {{ NationlityList.NationlityList[i+2].Nationality }} </mat-checkbox>
      <mat-checkbox *ngIf="i + 3 < NationlityList.NationlityList.length" (change)="onCheckboxChecked($event, NationlityList.NationlityList[i+3].Nationality)"> {{ NationlityList.NationlityList[i+3].Nationality }} </mat-checkbox>
      <mat-checkbox *ngIf="i + 4 < NationlityList.NationlityList.length" (change)="onCheckboxChecked($event, NationlityList.NationlityList[i+4].Nationality)"> {{ NationlityList.NationlityList[i+4].Nationality }} </mat-checkbox>
      <mat-checkbox *ngIf="i + 5 < NationlityList.NationlityList.length" (change)="onCheckboxChecked($event, NationlityList.NationlityList[i+5].Nationality)"> {{ NationlityList.NationlityList[i+5].Nationality }} </mat-checkbox>
  </div>
</div>
```

In component, I did replace the 'NationlityList.NationlityList' in mat-checkbox with the 'item' but it's not work.

Comment: include `this.NationlityList` sample data to reproduce issue or create a http://stackblitz.io

Comment: add `this.NationlityList` data in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things I see missing here (and it could be you have it but just didn't paste it into the snippet):

1. MAT_DIALOG_DATA isn't injected into the dialog component.
2. Once the data is injected, since it looks like you're passing in an object of type MatDialogConfig, you'd need to access the data from the config via the "data" property. I.e. `this.NationlityList = this.passedData.data`;
3. Lastly, and a minor thing, since you're subscribing here, you no longer have a dialogReference and instead have a subscription.

   const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(NationalityDailogComponent, 
         dialogConfig).afterClosed()
     .subscribe( data => {
       this.selectNationality = data;
               console.log(this.selectNationality);
     });

Comment: Thanks man!
I found out the reason and it's in 

dialogConfig.data = {
NationlityList: this.NationlityList
};

I should write it in

dialogConfig.data = this.NationlityList;